# how to recognize which signal emitted in slot?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, slot

I connect two signals to same slot. like this:

```
check = new QCheckBox();
connect(check, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(MySlot()));
connect(check, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(MySlot()));
```

I don't want to define an other slot. In `MySlot` is it possible to recognize which signal callbacks the slot?
How can I do this?

Comment: You can get that information with [QObject::sender()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender), but *do* note the warning in the documentation: "Warning: This function violates the object-oriented principle of modularity. ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use the `QMetaObject`/`QMetaMethod` data associated with the sender to get what you want (untested)...

```
void MyClass::MySlot ()
{
  auto index = senderSignalIndex();
  if (index == sender()->indexOfSignal("clicked()")) {

    /*
     * Got here as the result of a clicked() signal.
     */
  } else if (index == sender()->indexOfSignal("toggled(bool)")) {

    /*
     * Got here as the result of a toggled(bool) signal.
     */
  }
}
```

Rather than that, however, if you're using Qt5 I would suggest making use of the new signal/slot syntax along with lambdas...

```
check = new QCheckBox();
connect(check, &QCheckBox::clicked,
        [this]()
        {
          MySlot(false);
        });
connect(check, &QCheckBox::toggled,
        [this](bool toggled)
        {
          MySlot(true, toggled);
        });
```

Along with a change to the signature of `MySlot`...

```
/**
 * @param from_toggled_signal If true this call was triggered by a
 *                            QCheckBox::toggled signal, otherwise it's
 *                            the result of a QCheckBox::clicked signal.
 *
 * @param toggle_value If from_toggled_signal is true then this was the
 *                     value passed to QCheckBox::toggled, otherwise unused.
 */
void MyClass::MySlot (bool from_toggled_signal, bool toggle_value = false)
{
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 2):

New slots can be defined on the fly using lambdas :)

```
class MyClass : public QWidget {
  QSomeLayout m_layout{this};
  QCheckBox m_check;
  enum Signal { Clicked, Toggled };

  Q_SLOT void mySlot(Signal);
public:
  MyClass( ... ) : ... {
    m_layout.addWidget(&m_check);
    connect(&m_check, &QCheckBox::clicked, this, [this]{ mySlot(Clicked); });
    connect(&m_check, &QCheckBox::toggled, this, [this]{ mySlot(Toggled); });
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for your time. `enum Signal { Clicked, Toggled };` is good trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can also add your own context to the signal if that helps.  For instance I had a service that downloaded user avatars for multiple windows.  I needed the window to only load the user it was interested in something so I would pass in the user's id as the context.  Something like:

```
void UserService::downloadAvatar(const QString& url, const int context = 0) {
  ...// Make the http request, on finished:

  emit onAvatarDownloaded(context, responseBody);

}
```